# Excel Pivot table with more than one averaged value in rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following table:

[image]

What I would like to create is a pivot table like the following:

[image]

The only thing that I have managed to do is the following table, which is like a transposed version of what I want:

[image]

Do you think it is possible?

Regards

Thanasis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `values` in the rows.  This is automatically put in the columns but you can drag to rows:

[image]